# Textbox displaying, when using jquery and radio button to hide it

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, razor-2

Using the following code I am trying to hide the textbox, however, the script does not run.  I have debugged in multiple browsers with no action.  Can anyone tell me what the issue is.

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
if (!IsPost)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <br />
            <br />
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Group_Name)
            @Html.DropDownList("groupList",
                (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
                ViewBag.ListItem, "Select Group",
                new { @id = "selectedGroup",
                    @class = "form-control" })
            <br />
            <br />
            <button class="btn btn-primary"
                    >Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <br />
            <br />
            <label id="lblAddNew" class="label-default">
            Add new group</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radioAddNew" class="radio-inline" />
            <br />
            <br />

            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Group_Name, 
            new { @id = "txtBoxAddNewGroup" })

        </div>
    </div>
        @*<button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>*@
}

<div class="col-lg-2">


</div>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtBoxAddNewGroup").hide();
    $("#radioAddNew").click(function () {
        if (this.checked == true) {
            $("txtBoxAddNewGroup").show();
        }
        else {
            $("txtBoxAddNewGroup").hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I have tried the script in multiple places to no avail. This is using a layout, and the standard scripts are being rendered in the layout.

Comment: `$("#txtBoxAddNewGroup").show();` use the # symbol for IDs.

Comment: thanks, missed that, but the textbox isn't hiding to begin with